# Display correct tab when scrolling through MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, back, forward

I have a page which consists of three tabs each with labels. Clicking the label opens up each tab (by showing/hiding the divs). Each tab contains MySQL data, with arrows at the bottom of each tab to go the next 'page' of data.

My Problem, when you click the arrow, the page does indeed go to the next page of data, BUT the default tab (tab1) is made visible and the other two hidden, so if you're on tab two, hit the next arrow, you're taken back to tab1 and have to hit tab3 to see the data.

[Link to site here](http://www.thepcguy.org.uk/ship_image/Untitled-5.php?)

The script to change visibility of the tabs is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.tab-headers>a").click(function () {
        // Grab the href of the header
        var _href = $(this).attr("href");

        // Remove the first character (i.e. the "#")
        _href = _href.substring(1);

        // show this tab
        tabify(_href);
    });
    tabify();
});

function tabify(_tab) {
    // Hide all the tabs
    $(".tab").hide();

    // If valid show tab, otherwise show the first one
    if (_tab) {
        $(".tab a[name=" + _tab + "]").parent().show();
    } else {
        $(".tab").first().show();
    }
}

// On page load...
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Show our "default" tab.
    // You may wish to grab the current hash value from the URL and display the appropriate one
    tabify();
});
</script>
```

and tab2's code is:

```
<div class="tab">
<a name="tab2"></a>
<img src="images/glossary_shiptype.png" width="1643" height="952" /> 

  <div class="glossary_body">
  <table width="740" border="0">
    <?php do { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row_ship_type['term']; ?>:</td>
        <td><?php echo $row_ship_type['definition']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } while ($row_ship_type = mysql_fetch_assoc($ship_type)); ?>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="glossary_arrow_back">
  <?php if ($pageNum_ship_type > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
          <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_ship_type=%d%s", $currentPage, max(0, $pageNum_ship_type - 1), $queryString_ship_type); ?>"><img src="images/arrow_left.png" /></a>
          <?php } // Show if not first page ?>
  </div>

  <div class="glossary_arrow_forward">
  <?php if ($pageNum_ship_type < $totalPages_ship_type) { // Show if not last page ?>
          <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_ship_type=%d%s", $currentPage, min($totalPages_ship_type, $pageNum_ship_type + 1), $queryString_ship_type); ?>"><img src="images/arrow_right.png" /></a>
          <?php } // Show if not last page ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you have to pass tab id in paramater #tab1 or #tab2 or #tab3 and if you get #tab2 in query string and moving to #tab3 you have to remove #tab2

Comment: sorry I'm a bit lost in that answer with all the tabs, can you highlight areas of the code I need to amend. THank you

Comment: <?php printf("%s?pageNum_ship_type=%d%s%s", $currentPage, min($totalPages_ship_type, $pageNum_ship_type + 1), $queryString_ship_type,$tab_id); ?>

Comment: the two things are added %s and $tab_id